# hibernate mapping exception: could not determine type

Tags: java, hibernate

I found many links regarding this type of error but I didn't find anything explaining for Enumtypes. I downladed the latest hibernate jar files but no use!

Stacktrace of error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [dao-hbm.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ca.ups.tundra.dao.MessageSystemUserType, at table: History, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(SCANMSGSYS)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ca.ups.tundra.dao.MessageSystemUserType, at table: History, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(SCANMSGSYS)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass.validate(SingleTableSubclass.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1149)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 23 more
```

Following is my EnumUserType Class:

```
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType; 

public class EnumUserType<E extends Enum<E>> implements UserType {
```

extending the EnumUserType class:

```
public class MessageSystemUserType extends EnumUserType<MessageSystem> {
```

following is my enum class:

```
public enum MessageSystem { OPSYS, GIPLD, AA, CISCME,LOCAL, TFCS,LH, XPLD, CDC }
```

it was working good untill I added the last two enumtypes.

EDITED: this is how I am mapping the Enums,

```
<property name="messageSystem" type="ca.ups.tundra.dao.MessageSystemUserType" length="10" column="SCANMSGSYS"/>
```

Any suggestions in fixing this or about the error.

Comment: are those enums somehow map in the database?

Comment: @Gregory this is how I am mapping them, `<property name="messageSystem" type="ca.ups.tundra.dao.MessageSystemUserType" length="10" column="SCANMSGSYS"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout web.xml file for dependencies, whether they are good or not. 
checkout the .classpath filr for path of the jar files, it might be one solution.
check for missing jar files wich might be in classpath for project but not in your lib or vice-versa

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="../hibernateVersion.jar">
   <attributes>
       <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
   </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```